# Calculating probabilities from an exponential distribution

Tags: probability

> The length of time to be served in a cafeteria is exponentially distributed with mean 4.0minutes. What is the probability that a person is served in less than 3.0 minutes on at least four of the next six days?

Do I get the probability from the exponential distribution than do a binomial distribution to get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I get the probability from the exponential distribution than do a binomial distribution to get the answer?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to confirm